# Inonu-Wigner contraction in Weinberg Volume I

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, galilean-relativity, poincare-symmetry

In volume I of Weinberg quantum theory of fields, on page 61, Weinberg derived the commutation relations of the generators $H,P_i, J_i,K_i$ of the Poincare algebra, then he tried to take the nonrelativistic limits by doing the Inonu-Wigner contraction on page 62. He claims that $\boldsymbol{J}$'s are of order 1 and $\boldsymbol{P}$'s are of order $mv$. Then he says the $\boldsymbol{K}$'s are of order $1/v$.

My question is: why is the boost operator $\boldsymbol{K}$ of order $1/v$? Here $v$ is the nonrelativistic 3 velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is necessary since $$[\underbrace{K_i}_{{\cal O}(v^{-1})},\underbrace{P_j}_{{\cal O}(mv)}]=i\underbrace{M}_{{\cal O}(m)}\delta_{ij}.$$